# AngularJs - data not showing in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

I am trying a simple Spring MVS AngularJs REST application. All I am doing is fetching a list of customers from the database and passing it to the AngularJs controller.

In the AngularJs controller, while logging, I can see the promise and the data come through but for some reason the `ng-repeat` in the view does not pick it up. What am I doing wrong?

**Spring Controller..**.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cust_list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAllCustomers(Model model) {
    return new ModelAndView("cust_list", "listCustomers", getCustomers());
}
```

**Angular...**

```
angular.module('lilmoApp', ["ngResource"])

// service
.factory('CustomerService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/lilmo/cust_list').get();
}])

//controller
.controller('CustomersListController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'CustomerService', function ($scope, $resource, CustomerService) {
    $scope.customers = [CustomerService] 
    console.log($scope.customers);
}]);
```

**HTML view...**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
            <td>{{customer.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the javascript console with the data...

[image]

Though the data is coming through, it does not show up in the view, using the `ng-repeat`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the other answer is almost the solution BUT you are setting

```
$scope.customers = [CustomerService];
```

so its a array and index 0 is 
CustomerService you could set as

```
$scope.customers = CustomerService;
```

and use

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers.listCustomers">
```

otherwise without changes use

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers[0].listCustomers">
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that on first glance.

Comment: Thanks @Johan for your answer. It solved the problem. I left the array `[CustomerService]` as it is and used `customers[0].listCustomers`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your api result puts the customers inside a `listCustomers` child. This is useful because the `$resource` object attaches promise related fields to the root, so putting the actual data on a child makes it more clear. With that in mind, try this in your html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers.listCustomers">
```

It just looks like the `ng-repeat` is referencing the wrong array.

---

Update, as Johan said, you are placing the service into an array, so your $scope assignment needs to be updated as well by removing the unnecessary brackets.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Matt.